# Equation of a line parallel to two planes and passing through a point

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

Find the equations of the line passing through the point $(3,1,-2)$ and parallel to each of the planes $x-y+z=4$ and $3x+y-z=5$.

I started off by finding the normal vector from both of the planes $ \begin{vmatrix}
i & j & k \\
1 & -1 & 1 \\
3 & 1 & -1 
\end{vmatrix}  $ which worked out to $<0,4,4>$, but at this point I'm not sure where to continue.

Comment: that's the vector of the line: $<3, 1+4t, 4t-2>$. The normal of the normals of the planes will be parallel to both the planes. Then just extend that vector from the point.

Comment: The answer given in the textbook is $x-3=0$ and $y-z=1$, I can see where the first equation comes from, but i'm not sure how to get the second one

Comment: I don't see the point of giving the line as intersection of two planes. We could have just written $x-y+z = a$, $3x+y-z = b$ and then choose $a$ and $b$ such that $(3,1,-2)$ satisfies both of the equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  have found  the vector $\vec n=(0,4,4)^T$ that is orthogonal to the orthogonal of the first plane and orthogonal to the orthogonal of the second plane, so it is parallel to the two planes, and the line is
$$
\vec x=P+t\cdot\vec n
$$

where $P=(3,1,-2)$ is the given point.

---

So we have:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
3\\1+4t\\-2+4t
\end{pmatrix}
$$
that is equivalent to:
$$
\begin{cases}
x=3\\
y=1+4t\\
z=-2+4t
\end{cases}
$$
and, subtracting the last two equation we find:
$$
\begin{cases}
x=3\\
y-z=1+2\\
\end{cases}
$$
and that is another form of the equation of the line.

Comment: This much I understand, but the answer given in the textbook is $x-3=0$ and $y-z=1$, I'm not sure how to get the second equation from what we have here.

Comment: From what we have here the second equation seems wrong. The correct result is $y-z=3$

Comment: How do we compute that though?

Comment: I added to my answer. I hope it's useful :)

Comment: I was just working on parametric forms of line problems and got the same result you did. Very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

A directing vector of the sought line has to be orthogonal to the normal vectors of each plane, hence has to be collinear to the cross-product $\;\vec n_1\times \vec n_2$.

Thus a parametric equation of the line parallel to both planes, passing through point $A\,(3,1,-2)$ will be 
$$ M=A+t\,(\vec n_1\times \vec n_2). $$